# Chromebook certificate enrollment tokens

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, client-certificates, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I am having a little problem understanding the flow of this API (i am trying to understand the code written here:
http://www.chromium.org/administrators/certificate-management-extension-api-on-chrome-os )

We use this API to fetch a list of tokens, then only use the one with id "user".  Why is this the only id that is being used? what are those tokens? what does the id represents?

Later in the flow, the certificate is being imported under that token
platformKeys.importCertificate(userToken.id, certificate);

What does importing a certificate to a token id means? can we import multiple certificates under the same token id?

Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to know did you get any answer, let me know also. I am currently working on certificate enrollment related thing from extension.I have a another doubt how do we request for CSR and send it to CA and it trigger onClientCertificateReceived.

Comment: It has been some time since i've done this, but if i remember correctly there is an option to enroll either the logged-in user, or the entire device, and this is determined by the token id you are using.

Comment: From the API docs: " If a system-wide TPM token is available, the returned list will also contain the system-wide token with id "system". The system-wide token will be the same for all sessions on this device (device in the sense of e.g. a Chromebook). "